# Move Maildir contents to parent directory

Tags: linux, bash, file, file-io

i have to change my virtual mail folder tree.

I've configured a new mailserver and now i must import my old virtual mailboxes.

My old one directory was like /var/spool/vmail/domain.com/account/Maildir
with inside ( cur / new / ...).
I have to move like that /var/spool/vmail/domain.com/account

so i have to do this for every domain. Move all from Maildir to parent folder (the account folder).

I need a script cause there are hundreds of folders.

Thank you so much for any suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for f in /var/spool/vmail/*/*; do
  mv "$f/Maildir"/* "$f"/
  rmdir "$f/Maildir"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

How about `cd /var/spool/vmail/domain.com/account/Maildir; mv * ..`